# Validation fields not working how they should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, foreign-keys

I'm developing an app that requires the user to enter info into a form. Its has basic validation on some of the fields to check that the're not blank.

The user model has many user_entries

```
has_many :user_entries, dependent: :destroy
```

and the user_entry model belongs to user

```
belongs_to :user
```

the problem arises with the validation in the user_entry model

```
validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
```

before adding the foreign key user_id to the user_entries table this code worked fine, I could fill out the form with no problem and add the entries to the table. But I need to capture the current user id within the user_entries table so I can trace an entry to a user.

```
def create
  @user_entry = UserEntry.new(params[:user_entry])
  @user_entry.add_comp_connections_from_entered_competition(current_entered_competition)
  @user = current_user
  @user_entry = @user.user_entries.build
#--etc--#
```

removing the validation lets me do this, but I don't want to remove it. It seems that removing the foreign key lets me validate. But I want both to work, any help would be very much appreciated, thanks

Comment: can't you just add .... @user_entry.user = current_user ...

Comment: instead of this?
@ user = current_user
@ user_entry = @ user.user_entries.build

Comment: It worked perfectly thanks, I thought I was overcomplicating things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by SteveTurczyn changing

```
@user = current_user
@user_entry = @user.user_entries.build
```

to just

```
 @user_entry.user = current_user
```

makes the code work, like solving so many problems its a case of not over complicating things.

thanks again Steve Turczyn